# Shortest distance between two lines

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

Suppose L1 and L2 be the two lines in 3D, suppose P1 and P2 be two points on L1, L2 resp. such that distance(P2-P1) is shortest distance between L1 and L2. Does vector (P2-P1) need to be perpendicular to both L1 and L2? If so, then why? Is it true for 2D space also?

Comment: Short answer: yes, for both 2d and 3d. Experiment to confirm for 2D: draw two parallel lines on a sheet of paper, draw a line between them perpendicular to both, and then try to draw a shorter line between them that isn't perpendicular to both. If you're looking for a proof, the math SE is probably a better place.

Comment: Also check out Paul Bourke's [awesome math resources](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true.  Imagine this line,  perpendicular to both L1 and L2.  There are two cases, L1 and L2 are parallel (in which case all perpendicular lines between the two is equivalent, or they are like two propellers mounted on the same shaft, but at different angles.   The shaft (which is the only line that is perpendicular to both propellers), represents the shortest distance because no matter which direction you move along either propeller, away from the shaft, you are clearly increasing the distance, since any such line will form the third hypotenuse side of a right triangle with one side equal to the shaft itself, and the other side equal to the motion along the propeller.

If you move along both propellers, clearly, if you move away from the shaft in opposite directions, you are increasing the distance.  Even if the propellers are almost aligned, and you move along both propellers in the same direction , the line between the two points will again ne the hypotenuse of a right triangle where one side is the distance between the spin-planes of the two propellers , and the other side is a line in the spin plane of one of the two propellers .

Answer (score 0):

Take the function L1×L2->\R that, for two points P and Q on L1 and L2 respectively gives the squared distance between them:

```
f: L1×L2 -> \R
f(P, Q) = d(P, Q)^2 = (Q - P) . (Q - P)
```

where `(Q - P)` is a vector and  `.` is the scalar product. As the function f has a minimal at (P1, P2), the differentials df/dP and df/dQ are zero at (P1, P2). What is more:

```
df/dP = dP . (Q - P)
df/dQ = dQ . (Q - P)
```

If one evaluated those equations for (P1, P2), where the differentials are zero, that gives:

dP . (P2 - P1) = 0
   dQ . (P2 - P1) = 0

`dP` and `dQ` are vectors collinear with L1 and L2 respectively. Those two equations say that necessarily, the vector `P2 - P1` is perpendicular to the direction vectors of L1 and L2.